# uncorrelated vs independent in exponential family

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian (the joint measure admits a Gaussian density), we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated. If this true for all distributions in the exponential family?

More precisely, if $X$ and $Y$ have joint density of the form $f_\theta(x,y)\propto \exp(p(x,y,\theta))$ for some nice function $p$ (I'm ok to assume that $p$ is a polynomial), then is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated?

Comment: The question you want to ask is: if $f_\theta(x,y)\propto \exp(p(x,y,\theta))$  and $COV(X,Y)=0$ does it imply that we can write $f_\theta(x,y)\propto h(x)\cdot g(y)$ for some $h$ and $g$?

Comment: The answer is "No".

Comment: @Did: can you please construct (or give reference to) a counter-example?